# scanf and char pointers in C -- unexpected output

Tags: c, pointers, scanf, cstring

```
void main(int argc, char * argv[])
{ 
  FILE* inFile = NULL;
  char * bufferFromStdin;
  char buf[100];
  printf("Enter something:\n");
  scanf("%s", buf);
  printf("First scan from stdin is: %s\n", buf);

  if(buf == "THIS" || buf[0]=='T')
   {
    printf("THIS found first\n");
   }
   else {printf("Not Found first\n");}


   printf("Enter something again:\n");
   scanf("%s", bufferFromStdin);
   printf("Second scan from stdin is: %s\n", bufferFromStdin);
   if(bufferFromStdin == "THIS")
   {
    printf("THIS found second\n");
   }
   else {printf("Not Found second\n");}
}//main
```

gives me the output:
./test < testinput.txt 
Enter something:
First scan from stdin is: THIS  
THIS found first
Enter something again:
Second scan from stdin is: (null)
Not Found second

testinput.txt has one line of text "THIS"

this is what I get when I run the program with input as regular stdin
./test
Enter something:
THIS
First scan from stdin is: THIS
THIS found first
Enter something again:
THIS
Second scan from stdin is: (null)
Not Found second

How come the input cannot be saved to a char* when using either input method and how would I work around this? I need to get input from stdin by the keyboard and redirecting I/O as well. I think it's something to do with malloc();

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You should not compare strings as in `buf == "THIS"`. This doesn't compare strings, only pointers to strings! Use `strcmp()` to compare strings.

Comment: second time you are scanning from bufferFromstdin not from stdin

Comment: `bufferFromStdin` points to nothing. May be it needs allocated memory.

Answer (score 2):

You have two critical errors in your code. First of all, `bufferFromStdin` does not point to allocated memory. `scanf` requires a pointer to memory that has been previously allocated (such as `buf` in your example) where it will store the result. When you pass an uninitialized variable such as `bufferFromStdin` the result is undefined.

Second, the `==` operator in C compares two pointers, not what they are pointing to. Therefore, `buf == "THIS"` will never be true, since `buf` isn't pointing to a constant array. In order to compare two strings, use `strcmp`. Of course, both pointers need to point to something for this to work.

Also, as a side note, `main` should always return `int` not `void`.

Once you correct those two problems, your code should work:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{ 
  char buf[100];
  printf("Enter something:\n");
  scanf("%s", buf);
  printf("First scan from stdin is: %s\n", buf);

  if(strcmp(buf, "THIS") == 0) {
    printf("THIS found first\n");
  } else {printf("Not Found first\n");}

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a couple of programming errors in your code.

```
void main(int argc, char * argv[])
{ 
  FILE* inFile = NULL;
  char * bufferFromStdin;
  char buf[100];
```

you are allocating three pointer variables, using three different styles:

- `inFile` is properly initialized (NULL pointer).
- `bufferFromStdin` is not initialized.
- `buf` is initialized and points to a statically allocated area.

you probably want to check how one allocates memory in C.

```
  printf("Enter something:\n");
  scanf("%s", buf);
```

this `scanf` call is just a bit dangerous. if the user inserts a string that is longer than 99 chars (remember the \0 terminator), it will overflow the buffer. you probably want to check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621394/how-to-prevent-scanf-causing-a-buffer-overflow-in-c).

```
  printf("First scan from stdin is: %s\n", buf);

  if(buf == "THIS" || buf[0]=='T')
```

I'm sorry to say, but I find this quite funny! you want to test string equality (content, not pointer) and you see the first test does not work (you are comparing pointers) so you add a second test. check the [manual pages](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strcmp/).

```
   {
    printf("THIS found first\n");
   }
   else {printf("Not Found first\n");}
```

I find this also a bit ugly. you might want to stick to one [style for indenting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style).

```
   printf("Enter something again:\n");
   scanf("%s", bufferFromStdin);
```

you are using your uninitialized pointer. what happens here depends on your programming environment, operating system, compiler. a strong operating system will probably terminate your program. or you are corrupting some memory areas.

```
   printf("Second scan from stdin is: %s\n", bufferFromStdin);
   if(bufferFromStdin == "THIS")
```

same problem as above, but you forgot to implement your workaround.

```
   {
    printf("THIS found second\n");
   }
   else {printf("Not Found second\n");}
}//main
```